# How to make Nginx find existing index.php if it is requested by its name?

Tags: php, nginx, matomo

I have tried to install [Mamoto](https://matomo.org/matomo-on-premise/) (ex Piwik) on a local webserver (nginx via Docker) and have the following issues:

1. request to `http://localhost` -> works perfectly (it already executes `index.php`).
2. request to `http://localhost/index.php` -> gives 404 (it ignores the existence of `index.php`).

What is going on there with Nginx?

This is my nginx-config:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    index index.php;

    location ~ ^/(index|matomo|piwik|js/index|plugins/HeatmapSessionRecording/configs)\.php {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    ## deny access to all other .php files
    location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ \.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|htm|html|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|json)$ {
        allow all;
        ## Cache images,CSS,JS and webfonts for an hour
        ## Increasing the duration may improve the load-time, but may cause old files to show after an Matomo upgrade
        expires 1h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


}
```

The weird thing here: when I type a "die('test');" inside index.php, I can assure that index.php is definitely available at this location and gets executed on every request without a specific filename like "localhost".
But when `index.php` is requested by name (this is how Matomo works internally), then it gives 404.

Comment: The Nginx `internal` directive in the `location ~ ^/(index|...)\.php` block prevents the `/index.php` URI from being directly accessible. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal).

Comment: Thank you @RichardSmith! This was the final problem!